# Get the Months between two dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find out the months between two dates.e.g. if i start at 14th May and leave at 16th July. i have to pay full rent of May and July too. Also i am printing out the months in sorted order.

I am taking the input values as :

```
dateStart=datetime.date(input_list[0],input_list[1],input_list[2])
dateEnd=datetime.date(input_list[3],input_list[4],input_list[5])
```

INPUT as :

```
[2017,8,2,2018,1,1] --  format(yyyy,mm,dd)
```

OUTPUT i am trying to get as:

```
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Can someone help me out here how to achieve this.

Comment: Please show your code and data as a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem, and return an array `months` with the month names

```
import calendar
import pandas as pd

input_list = [2017,8,2,2018,1,1]
dateStart=pd.datetime(input_list[0],input_list[1],input_list[2])
dateEnd=pd.datetime(input_list[3],input_list[4],input_list[5])

months = []
y = dateStart.year
m = dateStart.month


while pd.datetime(y,m, 1) <= dateEnd:
    months.append(calendar.month_name[m])
    if m == 12: 
        y += 1
        m= 1
    else:
        m+=1
print(months)
['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
```

EDIT

```
import calendar
import pandas as pd

input_list = [2017,8,2,2018,1,1]
dateStart=pd.datetime(input_list[0],input_list[1],input_list[2])
dateEnd=pd.datetime(input_list[3],input_list[4],input_list[5])

months = []
new_months = []
y = dateStart.year
m = dateStart.month

ny=False
while pd.datetime(y,m, 1) <= dateEnd:
    if ny==True:
        new_months.append(calendar.month_name[m])
    else:
        months.append(calendar.month_name[m])
    if m == 12: 
        y += 1
        m= 1
        ny=True
    else:
        m+=1

print(new_months+months)
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: Thanks sdhaus. It was a great help. Could you also let me know how to get them in ascending order like January should come at first instead at last.

Comment: This should order the way you are looking for. It will only work for one new year sequence though

Answer (score 1):

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
ans = set()
while dateStart <= dateEnd:
    ans.add(dateStart.month)
    dateStart += datetime.timedelta(1)
print([months[x-1] for x in sorted(ans)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dateStart=datetime.date(input_list[0],input_list[1],input_list[2])
dateEnd=datetime.date(input_list[3],input_list[4],input_list[5])

# import the calendar 
import calendar

months = [ ]

for i in range(dateStart.year * 12 + dateStart.month, dateEnd.year*12+ dateEnd.month + 1):
    months.append(datetime.date((i-13) // 12 + 1, (i-1) % 12 + 1, 1).month)

# sort the months 
months = sorted(months)

# collect the Months Name in an order
months_Name = []

# code for months name
for i in months:
    months_Name.append(calendar.month_name[i])

# display the Months in an order    
print(months_Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import datetime

dateStart=datetime.date(2017,8,2)
dateEnd=datetime.date(2018,1,1)
dateRnd = datetime.date(dateStart.year, dateStart.month, 1)

while dateRnd<=dateEnd:
    print(dateRnd.strftime('%B'))
    dateRnd = datetime.date(dateRnd.year + int((dateRnd.month / 12)), ((dateRnd.month % 12) + 1), 1)
```